# random background image not loading

Tags: javascript, random, background-image

I am trying to activate the random background image for the "something" element, but without success, can anyone give a suggestion what I am doing wrong ?
This is from the `content-single-product.php`Woocommerce plugin

```
<div class="item-layout" id="something">
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = [
    "http://domainname.com/image-12.jpg",
    "http://domainname.com/image-11.jpg",
    "http://domainname.com/image-13.jpg",
    "http://domainname.com/image-14.jpg"
];

$("#something").css("background", "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ")");
</script>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <?php ...
        ?>

        <div class="summary">

            <?php ...               ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <?php 
            ...
        ?>

        <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_single_product'); // upsell ?>

    </div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

The css for `#something is width:100%; height:400px;`

Answer (score 1):

Got it, i missed the `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`
and moved the script outside of the `div`right below and works just fine